# Best way to smarten up this Swift code?

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift 3/Xcode8 but I'm slowly teaching myself some bits and pieces with the help of this site amongst other sources on the Internet.

It sounds like a complete noob question, but what is the best way to smarten up this code?

```
@IBOutlet var initialInvestigationCollection: [UIView]! {
    didSet {
        initialInvestigationCollection.forEach {
            $0.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func expandInitialInvestigationBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
        self.initialInvestigationCollection.forEach {
            $0.isHidden = !$0.isHidden
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like I want to create a function and call it in each method. The only problem is, `initialInvestigationCollection` and `expandInitialInvestigationBtn` are going to change every time and I intend to run these two functions on 10 different parts in the class.

Maybe I'm just being lazy by not wanting to repeatedly type it out!

Comment: I get what the code will do. But what do *you* want the code to do?

Comment: Essentially, the `initialInvestigationCollection` will be hidden until the user clicks the expand button which then expands the views contained within the `initialInvestigationCollection`.

Comment: Then you've done well. My answer, while different in syntax, is essentially the same. I go for explicitness (which is why I asked what you want). The code you have though works. Maybe you need to put in code review? http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you, I'll give codereview a go.

Comment: you can't animate `isHidden` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will re-post in code review if you post the link, but here's how I would do it:

```
@IBOutlet var initialInvestigationCollection: [UIView]! {
    didSet {
        setInitialInvestigationsHidden(to: true, animated: false)
    }
}

@IBAction func expandInitialInvestigationBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    toggleInitialInvestigationsHidden()
}

func toggleInitialInvestigationsHidden() {
    setInitialInvestigationsHidden(to: initialInvestigationCollection[0].isHidden)
}

func setInitialInvestigationsHidden(to hidden: Bool, animated: Bool = true) {
    if animated {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            initialInvestigationCollection.forEach { $0.isHidden = hidden }
        }
    }
    else {
        initialInvestigationCollection.forEach { $0.isHidden = hidden }
    }
}
```

It gives you flexibility to show, hide, or toggle, cleans up the usage in other parts of your code, but remains clear what the intention of the code is.